# Installing global node packages over Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (EBS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node application deployed over amazon EBS and it was working fine till I wrote a gulp task to be executed before deploying the application. now this gulp task needs gulp to be installed globally on server.

I wrote container command in EBS config file to install gulp globally but I get following error while deploying the application,

```
Command npm (npm install -g gulp) failed
```

My config file looks something like this:

```
packages:
  yum: 
    libcurl: []
    libcurl-devel: []
container_commands:
  npm:
    command: "npm install -g gulp"
  updatefunders:
    command: "./update_data.sh"
```

I am kind of stuck with this and this issue is preventing us from deploying gulp related updates to EBS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.